# Display the product attribute "color" count for a Woocommerce variable product(Total Numbers of Colors Available)

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-shortcode

I have some simple products and several Variable products with size and or color variants. On the products that are offered in various colors I would like to show on Product Page, how many color options exist for said product. So under product image on Product page it would show as "Available Colors: 5" or something similar based on how many available colors there are under the color variable for that product.

I have searched and not found much mention of how this is done in WooCommerce.
Also I'm using Woolentor plugin to customize default woocommerce pages.